# How to add pattern to ggplot colours

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image]

I built this ggplot that has a lot of components in the legend, so the colour palette is not very distinguishable between features. I'm wondering if theres a way to add a separate pattern to the colour palette, for example adding stripes to the scaffolds, so that some features can reuse colours. Is there someway to do this in ggplot?

Comment: From a data viz / data interpretability standpoint, you'd probably be better off rethinking your approach rather than finding a way to add more visual encodings. That might mean small multiples, or it might mean a different type of chart

Comment: Have a look at a synteny plot, something in the sphere of https://github.com/schneebergerlab/plotsr.

Comment: I agree with @camille. In your example, using patterned features will likely make the visualistion of your data harder to interpret, not easier. However, if there's absolutely no alternative, the `ggpattern` package and the command `scale_pattern_manual()` would be an option.

Comment: One non-patterned approach you could take is to ditch your colour pallette. All the literature I've read on the subject states it's not appropriate to use a continuous "colour ramp" (one that blends like yours) for categorical data. Also, people who are colour blind would not be able to interpret your plot, unless each value had a different pattern. I bet you could solve your issue by creating distinct colour values for each value. You could also, for instance, use shades of blue for the scaffold values, and other non-blue hues for the rest.